# Capitalize first letter of each line using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to know how I could capitalize the first letter of a row in JavaScript like in this PHP code :

```
<?php

$textParts = explode("\n", $text);
foreach ($textParts as $key => $value) {
   $textParts[$key] = ucfirst($value);
}

$text = implode("\n", $textParts);

$text="namjaga da geureochi mwo narago dareugetni
ni mameul da gajyeodo naragabeorigo maneun
namjaga da geureochi mwo"

?>

<p>
<?php echo $text; ?>
</p>
```

In JS, I get the text into the "Roman" DIV after a tranformation :

```
<div id="Roman"> </div>

<script>

<?php include("../../tools/js/romantool.js"); ?>
function affichar() {
  document.getElementById('Roman').innerHTML = latin_to_roman(
    document.getElementById('Parol').innerHTML
  );
}
affichar();

</script>
```

Does anyone know how I should proceed to do as in the previous PHP example ? Thank you !

Comment: what effort have you made on the javascript side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I would go right in between the two suggested answers so far. I would use javascript to replace the line breaks with a tag that will add structure around text e.g.

```
var str = document.getElementById('Parol').innerHTML;
str = '<span>' + str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '</span><span>') + '<span>';
document.getElementById('Roman').innerHTML = str;
```

And than style it in whichever way you want using CSS, your case would be

```
   span {
        display: block;
    }

    span:first-letter {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/58qkwezk/1/

Adding structure to your text will help you manipulate it much easier

Answer (score 2):

You could split the text on newlines, map the array so each line gets an uppercase first letter, then join with newlines:

```
text = text.split("\n").map(function(line) { 
           line = line[0].toUpperCase() + line.substr(1); 
           return line;
}).join("\n");
```

For example:

[image: Console.log showing example]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying just to display on the webpage.

How about this :

```
<style>
p.uppercase {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
</style>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

If you want to use JS:

```
$("p").css({"text-transform":"capitalize"});
```

Will  output:

```
This Is A Paragraph.
```

Comment: He only wants to capitalise the first letter of every line, not every word.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
    var sa = this.replace(/-/g, ' ');
    var saa = sa.toLowerCase();
    var sb = saa.replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])/g, function (m, p1, p2) {
        return p1 + p2.toUpperCase();
    });
    var sc = sb.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return sc;
};
```

Use like

```
'String'.capitalize();
```